# can't use sudo but only su

Tags: 12.04, sudo

As root, I created a new user and added to sudo group with

```
adduser myuser sudo
```

but when I try to sudo something I got the `Sorry, try again.` error.

The curious thing is that i can use `su` without any problem.

(I'm on a vps with a fresh install of ubuntu server 12.04)

Comment: Have you logged out and logged in again for the change to take effect? su takes a root password while sudo takes the users own password. Are you using the correct password?

Comment: while logged in as the new user run `id` in a terminal what's the output? Have you set a password for the new user?

Comment: @Sylwester yes, I also rebooted

Comment: @WarrenHill the `id` output is `uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),27(sudo)` and yes, I've set the new user's password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `su` you use the root password. With `sudo`, you use your account password.

The errors looks like you've been entering the root password.

Comment: omg, it was that! I'm such a noob!!

Answer (score 1):

`Sorry, try again` error means the password is wrong, this can be because changes have not been effected(logging in and out can solve this), or you are somehow entering the wrong details .